# Is there a practical difference between [electoral-system] and [voting-systems]?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

[electoral-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral-system) - 18 Qs, no excerpt

[voting-systems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-systems) - 186 Qs with this excerpt

> For questions about rule systems for gathering and counting votes. Not for questions about country-specific rules but for the theory and practice of voting systems. Examples include proportional-representation and first-past-the-post.

I'm thinking the two tags really mean the same thing, but, ironically, the latter is being misused. [electoral-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral-system) is clear we're talking about the mechanism by which officials are elected. [voting-systems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-systems) sounds like it could be used to describe the system by which ballots are cast and counted. I would say it needs to be a synonym of [electoral-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral-system) for disambiguation.

Comment: I've suggested a [electoral-system] as a synonym of [voting-systems]. If you agree, vote on it here: https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/voting-systems/synonyms

Comment: Heh. You need a score of 5 and I have a score of 4. Figures.

Answer (score 6):

#### A difference could be created, but doesn't exist in current usage

The most natural distinction to apply comes from the excerpt for [voting-systems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-systems) which states that it is "Not for questions about country-specific rules". A natural conclusion is that a different tag *could* exist for country-specific rules, and [electoral-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral-system) seems suitable to me.

However, current use of the tags doesn't support that distinction. Right now, questions about voting/election theory and questions about country-specific voting/election systems exist in significant numbers in each tag. Trying to create such a distinction would split both tags and require a lot of manual retagging. Instead I think it's appropriate to simply unify the tags.

In terms of which tag should be the "main" one and which should be the synonym, I would usually go with leaving the more popular tag and making the other a synonym, but in this case I have a slight preference for [electoral-system](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/electoral-system). The main reason is that the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voting_system) for "Voting system", which is currently linked on the [voting-systems](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/voting-systems) [info page](https://politics.stackexchange.com/tags/voting-systems/info), redirects to the "Electoral System" page; Wikipedia isn't an *authority* on the subject, but it would be nice for the tag names to reflect the concepts we link to describe them. It's only a slight preference though. I would also remove the "Not about country-specific rules" part of the usage guide.

**TL;DR** The tags are the same in current usage, and merging them seems more beneficial than creating an artificial divide.